# Managing ephemeral view state

Tags: swiftui

I'm working on a card game, and its primary view shows a grid of cards. The player can select and deselect up to 3 cards, and once exactly 3 cards are selected the model is called to increase or decrease the player's score according to some rules. I'm trying to find the best way to keep track of currently selected cards. Since this is ephemeral state, I added a @State variable to my main view:

```swift
struct GameView: View {
    @ObservedObject var game: GameViewModel
    @State private var selectedCardIds: Set<Int> = [] // Here!

    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(...) { card in
            CardView(card: card, selectedCardIds: $selectedCardIds)
                .onTapGesture {
                    game.choose(card: card, selectedCardIds: &selectedCardIds)
                }
        }
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    let card: GameViewModel.Card
    @Binding var selectedCardIds: Set<Int>
    private var selected: Bool { selectedCardIds.contains(card.id) }
    ...
}
```

The problem: managing the `selectedCardIds` variable requires quite a bit of code, so I moved it to my view model shown below. But is there a better way to manage the view state? I'd appreciate any suggestions to improve the structure of my code.

View model:

```swift
class GameViewModel: ObservableObject {
    ...

    func choose(card: Card, selectedCardIds: inout Set<Int>) {
        if selectedCardIds.count >= model.setSize {
            selectedCardIds.removeAll()
        }

        toggle(card: card, selectedCardIds: &selectedCardIds)

        model.cleanUpTheTable()
        model.tryToMatchCards(withIds: selectedCardIds)
    }

    private func toggle(card: Card, selectedCardIds: inout Set<Int>) {
        guard card.state != .matched else { return }

        if selectedCardIds.contains(card.id) {
            selectedCardIds.remove(card.id)
        } else {
            selectedCardIds.insert(card.id)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to put the selected card set also into the view model as `@Published` property. This avoids the `inout` parameters

```
class GameViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedCardIds = Set<Int>()

    func choose(card: Card) {
        if selectedCardIds.count >= model.setSize {
            selectedCardIds.removeAll()
        }

        toggle(card: card)

        model.cleanUpTheTable()
        model.tryToMatchCards(withIds: selectedCardIds)
    }

    private func toggle(card: Card) {
        guard card.state != .matched else { return }

        if selectedCardIds.contains(card.id) {
            selectedCardIds.remove(card.id)
        } else {
            selectedCardIds.insert(card.id)
        }
    }
}
```

And instead of a `@State/ObservedObject` put it into the environment

```
struct GameView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var game: GameViewModel

    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(...) { card in
            CardView(card: card)
                .onTapGesture {
                    game.choose(card: card)
                }
        }
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var game: GameViewModel
    
    let card: GameViewModel.Card
    private var isSelected: Bool { game.selectedCardIds.contains(card.id) }
    ...
}
```